# Spring Security 5.7 - How to return custom UserDetails

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I've seen a lot of examples where a user creates a custom `UserDetailsService` in order to override the `loadUserByUsername` method and return a custom implementation of a `UserDetails` object.

This was done previously with sth like this

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```

Now with the new version I'm confused on how to do this

I created a `Bean` and used the `JdbcUserDetailsManager`, I can configure my custom queries for users and authorities tables

```
  @Bean
  public UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager(DataSource dataSource) {
    String usersByUsernameQuery = "select username, password, enabled from tbl_users where username = ?";
    String authsByUserQuery = "select username, authority from tbl_authorities where username = ?";
    
    JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
      
    userDetailsManager.setUsersByUsernameQuery(usersByUsernameQuery);
    userDetailsManager.setAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery(authsByUserQuery);
    
    return userDetailsManager;
  }
```

but how to return a custom `UserDetails` object with an extra field, e.g. an email with the new version?

Comment: By not using the JdbcUserDetailsManager and implementing a custom one using the UserDetailsService interface

Comment: @Toerktumlare i'm missing sth here i guess. As i saw this Service only queries the db for the user info. it doesnt do any authentication. do i need to implement an `authenticationprovider` too? Sorry i started working with this new version and i had been using EE 7 all these years, so any help is appreciated. I could use the deprecated ones for which i have found many examples, but i want to do this the right way. thank you

Comment: the help i can give you is that you should read the spring security documentation on their webpage before asking on stack overflow as you are asking basic questions that can be answered by actually reading the docs

Comment: Ok what I did was to disable the whole `JdbcUserDetailsManager` stuff from SecurityConfig class and I created a custom `UserDetailsService` and custom `UserDetails` class and it worked. I was confused because I thought that somehow I had to create a `@Bean` inside the config class, but it worked without anything extra.

Comment: @Toerktumlare thank you for your comment. I didnt know that spring will register the class even though it is outside the `config` class and since all the other examples had some connection with the custom UserDetailsService class inside the config class, i was very confused. thnx again!

Comment: when you create a `@Bean` during the startup of the application, the dependency framework of spring will inject all registered beans into classes that needs them. Its a VERY common mistake that people register beans AND then set beans manually which is completely unnecessary. The whole purpose of having dependency injection is that it works automatic. So when you configure spring security to use for instance FormLogin. All you need to do is what you have done and it will inject the UserDetailsService automatically where it is needed in the framework.

Comment: i strongly recommend that you read the `architecture` section of the spring security documentation as if done so you will know more than 95% of all people asking questions here. And reading the rest of the docs will make perfect sense and the docs will answer most questions for you

Comment: @Toerktumlare thank you once again for your comments! I'll read it asap in order to better understand it and not to loose 2 more days of searching!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK after many tries what I did was to remove completely `JdbcUserDetailsManager` stuff from my custom `SecurityConfig` class and I created a custom `UserDetailsService` and custom `UserDetails` class and it worked.

So security config class had no code regarding the authentication of the users.
I was very confused because I thought that somehow I had to create a `@Bean` inside the config class, implement the authentication myself and in general that all this authentication code **had** to be done inside the config class, but it worked with this approach.

```
@Service
public class MyCustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

  @Autowired
  UserRepository userRepository;
  
  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    
    if (user == null) {
      throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with username: " + username);
    }
    return MyUserDetails.build(user);
  }
}
```

And the details class

```
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {

  private String username;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  @JsonIgnore
  private String password;

  private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

  public MyUserDetails(String username, String firstName, String lastName, String password,
      Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    this.username = username;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.password = password;
    this.authorities = authorities;
  }

  public static MyUserDetails build(User user) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream()
        .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getAuthority()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new MyUserDetails(
        user.getUsername(), 
        user.getFirstName(),
        user.getLastName(),
        user.getPassword(), 
        authorities);
  }

  @Override
  public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
  }

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  @Override
  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  @Override
  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
      return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
      return false;
    MyUserDetails user = (MyUserDetails) o;
    
    return Objects.equals(username, user.username);
  }
}
```

Also check [Spring Security Architecture](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture)